# Напишите функцию, которая принимает массив строк arr как аргумент и возвращает количество слов длиной 5

Tags: javascript, массивы

Долго думал, пробовал и так не смог выйти к нужному результату. Снизу мои попытки:

```
arr = ['apple', 'peach', 'ice', 'water']
function countOfWordsOf5Letters(arr){
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i].length === 5) sum++ ;
    return sum;
  }
}
console.log(countOfWordsOf5Letters(arr));
```

Comment: Отформатировал вам код. Теперь видите в чем проблема?

Comment: return sum переместите вне цикла for, а лучше и проще используйте arr.filter(). Добавил ответ ниже.

Answer (score 3):

```
const words = ['1111', '11111', '1111', '11111'];

const wordsFilter = arr => {
  
  return arr.filter(item => item.length == 5).length;
}

console.log(wordsFilter(words));
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
function countOfWordsOf5Letters(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((r, i) => r += +(i.length == 5), 0);
}
console.log(countOfWordsOf5Letters(['1234', '12345', '1234', 'abc', '12345']));
```

Comment: `i.length == 5 ? 1 : 0` -> `+(i.length == 5)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr = ['apple', 'peach', 'ice', 'water', 'websocket', 'me']

function countOfWordsOf5Letters(arr) {
  let sum = 0;
  let str = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    str = arr[i]
    if (str.length === 5) sum++;

  }
  return sum;
}
console.log(countOfWordsOf5Letters(arr));
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/coding-style